# I want to add discount to existing quote using controller file Magento 2

Tags: magento2, addtocart, controllers

I have my custom code , which generates the new customer and add products to that customer's cart.This code is working fine for me.I want to add some discount to that customer programmatically. So how can I add some discount programmatically for the customer's cart using this controller file.

```
<?php
/**
 *
 * Copyright © 2015 Detailcommerce. All rights reserved.
 */
namespace Mp\Accountmanager\Controller\Accountmanager;

class Amsave extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $cart;
    protected $product;
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;
    protected $quoteModel;
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $cartManagementInterface;
    protected $cartRepositoryInterface;
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quoteModel,
         \Magento\Quote\Api\CartManagementInterface $cartManagementInterface,
         \Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->_customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
        $this->cartManagementInterface = $cartManagementInterface;
        $this->quoteModel = $quoteModel;
        $this->cartRepositoryInterface = $cartRepositoryInterface;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->product = $product;
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $post = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
        $state = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');

        $customerFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');

        $websiteId = $storeManager->getWebsite()->getWebsiteId();

        $store = $storeManager->getStore();  // Get Store ID

        $storeId = $store->getStoreId();

        $customer = $objectManager->create('Mp\Accountmanager\Model\Accountmanager');

        $customer_new = $customerFactory->create();

                    $customer_new->setWebsiteId($websiteId);

                    $customer_new->setEmail($post['customer_email']);

                    $customer_new->setFirstname($post['customer_contact_person']);

                    $customer_new->setLastname($post['customer_contact_person']);

                    $customer_new->setPassword($post['customer_email']);

                   $customer_new->save();




                    $cartId = $this->cartManagementInterface->createEmptyCart(); //Create empty cart
                    $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId); // load empty cart quote
                    $quote->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId());
                    $customer= $this->_customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customer_new->getId());
                    $quote->setCurrency();
                    $quote->assignCustomer($customer);

                     if($customerSession->getProcuctIdsSm() != NULL)
                    {
                    $products_arraysm = $customerSession->getProcuctIdsSm();
                    $products_arraysm = explode(',', $products_arraysm);
                     foreach ($products_arraysm as $value) 
                    {
                        $_product = $this->productRepository->getById($value);    
                        $quote->addProduct($_product,1);
                    }
                    }
                    $quote->collectTotals()->save();


            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__("Product Added successfully"));

    $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
}
}
```

Please help me!!! Your answer would be appreciated...Thanks

Comment: Did you ever get your answer?

Comment: did you find any answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

Try following way:

```
$quote->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
$quote->setCouponCode($couponCode)->collectTotals();
$this->cartRepositoryInterface->save($quote);
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about how can i apply custom discount using custom controller ?

Comment: If i use the coupon code , then it is working fine.                                               $quote->setCouponCode('9898989')->collectTotals()->save();                             But i want to add custom discount price instead of coupon code. Thanks!!!

Comment: I also want to add custom discount amount from api not the coupon code. Please help